# Packaging C binary in java

Tags: java, c

I have a java program that requires the calling of a C binary to perform some computations.

The way I'm currently doing this is using a ProcessBuilder and running the C program as an external binary.

However, I'd like to migrate this program into the cloud, so I need everything to be in one java project and calling the C program as an external binary would not be possible. Is there some way for me to package the C binary into the jar somehow and call that in my program?

Comment: @Mansuro: I think that he already knows this. The issue appears to be one of packaging. I don't think that the binary can go inside of the jar, although I could be wrong.

Comment: This really is more of a question of packaging and deployment rather than Java/C.  How are you packaging up your program and deploying it to the cloud?  What exactly requires it to be "one Java project", whatever that means?

Comment: What sort of platform are you going to be running on? "The cloud" isn't very specific. I've done this before, but you have to know that your binary will be compatible with the host system and that you'll be able to extract it somewhere.

Comment: It's JNI.  The details of building and deployment are highly platform-dependent.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels well you can definitely include it as a resource then self-extract it. I've done exactly this before, partly just because I'm better at more Java code than our build/deploy layer coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binary file can be packaged into a JAR. When your program is running, you can abstract your binary file out of JAR and store it into a temp file, and execute it.

When the JAR is running, its path can be obtained as:

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("temp_name", "suffix");
temp.deleteOnExit();
InputStream input = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your_binary_file");
WRITE_INPUTSTREAM_TO_FILE(input, temp);
```

And now, you got an temp file which can be executed!

Comment: yes, you can pack everything to a jar file, just like in case of Java source, but it was not a qs. You'll need to describe how to load the C binary to answer it.

Comment: If you want just to run executable, you don't need to do any JNI stuff. See my update in the answer. It's simpler and shorter than reading the whole jar and then retrieving the executable.

Comment: Yes, I tried getResourceAsStream method and that works. Thanks for your proposal. @OlegGryb

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, but I don't consider it as a good one. I still think that deploying a C library with JNI interfaces exposed would be a better option.

```
1. Crete C library with JNI interfaces exposed.
2. Pack the library to a JAR.
3. At run time use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream to get a stream to your resource
4. Store the stream to a file
5. Use System.load(path-to-file) to load the library
```

I'm omitting details about JNI - it's a big and separate topic that you should explore yourself.

If you simply want to run an executable, and not to use a C lib, you can skip #1 and #5 above and simply run the executable that you've stored in the file.